# show image file name from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file

so, I have this type of add product page

[image]

Now, when i click Edit from the browse product section below.. my page looks like this..

[image]

But, the problem is with Image file. I am not able to display stored image file's name as SELECTED file. near browse button.Hope you guys understand what I am asking here.

Comment: Please post your code also?

Comment: Of course you cannot display it as the selected file. That's not how the input type=file works. If a file was (past tense) stored, you can display the file name elsewhere in the form, but not as part of the input type=file field.

Comment: Just display image on edit page. And In hidden input value store image filename. If you want to store new image than just browse new image and submit. After that in php just check If in the post data file come than replace new file in database else not do.

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you @Gaurav

Answer (score -1):

When you save the image against the product initially the file name should be saved in the database against that product. When you edit this product we can fetch this filename from the respective db column and display it in a `<span>`. Hope this helps.